# How would you insert a node at the start of a sorted linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures

In the below code I am trying to insert a node at the beginning of the linked list

When I try to insert a value 2 it should be inserted at the beginning of the LL that is before the start node as it is the smallest value

```java
class Main{  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        class Node{
              int data;
              Node next;
             Node(int data){
                this.data = data; 
             }
             Node(int data, Node next){
                 this.data=data;
                 this.next=next;
                 }
             public Node insert(Node start, int x){
                 if (start == null || start.data > x) { 
                     start = new Node(x,start.next);
                     return start;
                 }
                     Node p = start;
                     while (p.next != null) {
                      if (p.next.data > x) 
                          break;
                      p = p.next;}
                     p = p.next = new Node(x,p.next);
                      return start;
                      }
            }
    
        Node start = new Node(10);
        Node p = start;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            p = p.next=new Node(20+10*i);
        }
        p.insert(start,2);
        for(p=start;p!=null;p=p.next) {
        System.out.println(p.data); 
        }
        
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
40
```

Desired Output:

```
2
10
20
30
40
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution to this is that you need a class that wraps around your nodes and maintains a reference to the head of the list:

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node head = null;

    private class Node {
        private final T value;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T value, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public void insert(T value) {
            assert value.compareTo(this.value) >= 0;
            if (next == null || value.compareTo(next.value) <= 0)
                next = new Node(value, next);
            else
                next.insert(value);
        }
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        if (head == null || value.compareTo(head.value) <= 0)
            head = new Node(value, head);
        else
            head.insert(value);
    }

    public Stream<T> stream() {
        return Stream.iterate(head, n -> n != null, n -> n.next)
                .map(n -> n.value);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a 'dummy' head node. Arguably not as elegant but does avoid some code repetition. Here's that alternative (with recursion changed to iteration for good measure).

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final Node head = new Node(null, null);

    private class Node {
        private final T value;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T value, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        Node previous = head;
        while (previous.next != null && previous.next.value.compareTo(value) < 0)
            previous = previous.next;
        previous.next = new Node(value, previous.next);
    }

    public Stream<T> stream() {
        return Stream.iterate(head.next, n -> n != null, n -> n.next)
                .map(n -> n.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the above correction to my code doesn't seem to be inserting a node at the front even though it is smaller than the start node. I was referring to Schaum outlines' Data Structures and algorithms for java

Comment: @KenniethMenezes I added a complete solution